# Highlight differences between two records from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Say I have two records from the *same* SQL Server table, and I want to see only the columns where the data is not the same between these two records. There are many columns, and the differences are not visually obvious.

Is there a query or keyword in SSMS I can use to highlight the columns where the data is different?

Example:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data1 | data30 | somedat | data | etc. |
| data1 | data29 | sonedat | data | etc. |

I would want to return:

| Column2 | Column3 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data30 | somedat | etc. |
| data29 | sonedat | etc. |

because Column2 and Column3 are have different values between the two records.

Comment: You will have write custom logic to do this. Without anymore information than you provided there isn't much in the way of detail I can offer.

Comment: @SeanLange what can I provide to help?

Comment: Where are you (or your users) looking at the output? In management studio? No. Not unless you write a plugin. In a user interface written by you or another programmer? Write the logic to do the highlighting in the user interface.

Comment: @allmhuran I am in SSMS and it is just for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are just looking for :
Select distinct Field1, Field2, Field3... field-n from whateverTable

Update: I see you wanted to see different ones! But still distinct might help you building that logic! Because distinct should give you non-duplicate records!

Comment: @NirmalSubediyes distinct would work but as far as I am aware (and correct me if i'm wrong) distinct only works on one column at a time. I want to check every column in the table for differing data.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What's the column, or set of columns, that says two rows should be comparable? e.g.: if `Column1` is meant to be the business key then why are there two rows with `data1` values? How would you handle the case when two rows have `data1` and `data10` but were meant to be the same?

Comment: If, in advance, you know two rows that you want to compare it seems that in SQL you could write logic that `unpivot`s them, `except`s them against each other, and finally `pivot`s the differing unpivoted rows to show only the columns that are differing between the two rows.